# I lost my changes in Git

Tags: git

I am new in Git
My problem is I commited and pushed somechamges (Login page editor with translation--see screenshot), after other commits and pushes from my collegues, I pulled and the changes are lost.
what can I do ?
[image]

Comment: Your changes may be overriden by some others. Check the history of that perticular file.

Comment: How do you merged your branch?

Comment: I didnt make the merge, other collegue did it. I even added a new file and this file deleted after the last merge. does the merge undo fix my problem ?

Comment: Use `git reflog`.  If your coworkers forced their changes it will get messy for you.  If they just made _new_ commits then you should be able to get what you need from your earlier commit.

Comment: Type `git log` and see whether your commit still be present.  If it is, then you can do `git checkout <SHA-1>` using the hash of your commit.  You should immediately have all the files you thought you lost.

Comment: yes in log and as you see in screenshot my commit exists. Do you think I made wrong pull ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screen shot, all your behavior is right.

If you lose some thing(files/code), it must be your collegues delete them.

Comment: I think so, maybe my collegue pushed force without pulling last commits then he merged.

Answer (score 1):

It may be your colleague's fault. Ask them if they touched somehting.